# Socket.io - is it ok to modify socket.rooms set

Tags: node.js, web, websocket, socket.io

My use-case for Socket.io is to keep track of pages people are on and the underlying elements they have selected or are currently on. This means that there has to be a hierarchy in the rooms structure. Simply concatenating the room to the previous room could be a way to go, however this way you are not able to distinguish them when different layers have the same name by chance.

Because of this I thought of adding 'scope' variables when joining rooms. This gets me to the question is it ok to modify socket.io's socket.rooms set. Since it is a set I would have to do it like the following:

```
if (socket.rooms.has(room)) {
      socket.rooms.delete(room);
      socket.rooms.add({
        name: room,
        scope: data.scope,
      });
    }
```

Firstly I am curious if Socket.io relies heavily on the construction of the socket.rooms set or if this is just not a very good/nice solution.

Secondly I am curious to know if someone knows a better concept for my general use-case

Comment: Couldn't the hierarchy be represented in the name instead? Using the css selector

Comment: Can you elaborate your vision

Comment: On hover/focus, compute the css selector to that element/section/widget, leave any other room, and join the room whose name is that css selector

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to conclude myself that Socket.io relies on socket.rooms and that  modifying a room from the object.rooms set is not very conventional and will also cause socket.io's rooms to break. I believe it is common to keep track of extra information myself.